# Is it possible to add authorization to ReDoc UI page? OPENAPI documentation

Tags: openapi, redoc

Is there a way to add authorization to redoc ui, so only registered users could have access to documentation and interactive api calls? Maybe, any integration with the Keycloak?

API is using Flask, flask-smorest.